# Prove $\cos(2x)-\cos(4x)=2\sin(3x)\sin(x)$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

> Use the expansion of $\cos(3x-x)$ and $\cos(3x+x)$  to show that $\cos(2x)-\cos(4x)=2\sin(3x)\sin(x)$

I am so confused. I get that $\cos(2x)-\cos(4x)=\cos(3x-x)-\cos(3x+x)$

This part I don't get; the expression above equals to:

$(\cos(3x)\cos(x)+\sin(3x)\sin(x))-(\cos(3x)\cos(x)-\sin(3x)\sin(x))$ but I don't understand how.

and when simplified this is equal to $2\sin(3x)\sin(x)$

Comment: What *did* you get when you simplify the expression?

Comment: @player3236 23

Comment: And so you have proved the result, quite successfully I might add.

Comment: Or do you mean you do not know the identity $\cos (A \pm B) = \cos A \cos B \mp \sin A \sin B$?

Comment: @player3236 i found the answer Kavi told me I had forgotten it as I am in integration and had done triganometry 3 month ago thank you-!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos (2x)-\cos (4x)=\cos (3x-x)-\cos (3x+x)=[\cos (3x) \cos x +\sin (3x) \sin x] -[\cos (3x) \cos x -\sin (3x) \sin x]=2\sin (3x) \sin x$.

I have used the formulas $\cos (A+B)=\cos A \cos B-\sin A \sin B$ and $\cos (A-B)=\cos A \cos B+\sin A \sin B$.

Comment: Yesss you used that formula thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)=2\sin A\sin B$$
Let, ${A+B}=C$ and ${A-B}=D$

Thus, $$\cos D-\cos C=2\sin\left(\frac{C+D}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{C-D}{2}\right)$$
Now, using this, put the values of $C$ and $D$, then find the answer.

Comment: This approach is much simpler. Also, the formula $cos(A-B)-cos(A+B)=2sinAsinB$ can be proved by subtracting the elementary formulas of $cos(A+B)$ and $cos(A-B)$